# Adding elements of an array parallelly to elements of another array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, append

I have two lists:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));  

List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
```

I want to add them in such a way that the result is 1a2b3c and suppose if a is null, then the result should be 2b3c.

I am new to programming so not sure how to do this change.

I tried doing it using separate checks for all the values and it is working that way. But want to know if there is any simpler way to do this.

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

This is called zipping collections, see this post: https://www.baeldung.com/java-collections-zip

```
IntStream
  .range(0, Math.min(list1.size(), list2.size()))
  .mapToObj(i -> list1.get(i) + ":" + list2.get(i))
  // ...
```